# How do I add new elements to this type of array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am wondering what I have to do to add something to:

```
$setting = array(
    'element' => array(
        array(
            'elelemt_name' => '',
            'element_path' => ''
        ),
    )
);
```

The object I want to add is:

```
    array(
        'elelemt_name_two' => '',
        'element_path_two' => ''
    ),
```

the end result would be:

```
$setting = array(
    'element' => array(
        array(
            'elelemt_name' => '',
            'element_path' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'elelemt_name_two' => '',
            'element_path_two' => ''
        ),
    ),
);
```

The catch: $setting = array(); could be $a = array(); or $b = array() or anything, So I have no idea how I would add something when the variable containing the array could named anything.

What I do know, is that the first key, $element, will always be $element. So that part can be hard coded.

I was thinking of writing a function like:

```
function add_array($type, $array){
    if(is_array($array) && is_array($type)){
        array_push($type, $array);
    }
}
```

Then I could call it as such:

```
$array = array(
    'element_name_two' => '',
    'element_path_two' => ''
)
```

`add_array($setting['element'], $array);`

does this make sense? or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is just to add it.

```
$setting['element'][] = array('element_name_two' => '','element_path_two' => '');
```

If you want a function to adjust the contents of an  array you should pass in the array by reference.

```
function add_array(&$type, $array){
    if(is_array($array) && is_array($type)){
        array_push($type, $array);
    }
}
```

Comment: would the "by refrence" part work if you don't know it will be "$setting", as stated it could be $a, $b, $fdcdf, $sample....and so on. it could be anything.

Comment: If whatever is passed to the function .... so if you wanted to perform the behavior on $a then `add_array($a, $newArray);` ... it will work as well on subarrays as well `add_array($setting['element'], $newValue);`

Comment: thank you this is what I wanted :D, pass by reference has always confused me

Answer (score 2):

No need for heavy artillery:

```
$setting['element'][] = $new_array;
                   ^^--- short-hand syntax for array_push()
```